# MySQL PDO delete users older than 2 days, delete content from other tables with user_id

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I am making a small system to clean up the database. Every person that visits the site gets put in the db, but if he/she doesn't register, he/she should be removed from the database with a cronjob or so if the time when he/she first visited the site is longer than 2 days. The date is stored in MySQL as a timestamp but looks like this: `2013-06-05 01:18:43`.

So what I thought about doing was the following:

```
$STH = $DBH->query("DELETE FROM user WHERE type=0 AND joindate < ".date('d-m-Y H:i:s',time()-$userLife));
```

Like this, the format of the timestamp is the same as in MySQL. I'm using `$userLife` so I can easily adjust this var at the beginning of my script.

The problem is however, that I also need to do queries for other tables containing this `user_id`. For example the table `pages`:

`id | user_id | level | time | views`

In this table, it is possible that there are multiple instances of `user_id`.

Can this be done in one single query, or do I need to first loop through all the users, for each user then do the DELETE-queries for 3 other tables and after that loop delete all the `user`s?

Comment: You can use JOINs with DELETE queries as well. It seems you are mixing mysql NOW() function with PHP code.

Comment: You're right, it should have been `time()` in php. Does the delete delete that row from all the tables? And what if there are multiple rows with that certain `user_id` in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd define things with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, and define an `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which automagically will delete all that related data for you. If that's not possible for some reason (stuck with a MyISAM table for instance), you could simply `JOIN` the related tables (yes, you can [delete from more then 1 table at once](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html)). If it's your first time doing that, do it on a testdatabase, and certainly not in production.

Comment: Pheew, didn't know MySQL had so many options! Seems like my db does support it. So say I go to `pages`-table, go to relational view, I select the Foreign key constraint (in this case `'mysite'.'user'.'id'`), for `ON DELETE` I choose `CASCADE`, but what do I choose for `ON UPDATE`, and is the `constraint name` important?

Comment: You can cascade on update if you ever imagine yourself updating an id (I usually just omit the whole `ON UPDATE` clause), the name is not of importance, but given the opportunity you'd of course make it a description you'll recognize in a few years ;)

Comment: I'm never going to change the id either, but I was just using the interface from `phpMyAdmin` instead of writing a query to do so so I have some guidance :p

Comment: Ah, well, for future reference, it's just `ALTER TABLE pages ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;`. Mind you, if your data is 'corrupt' (i.e.: there are invalid user_id's) or the types of the columns don't match _exactly_, MySQL won't let you do it until you've fixed that).

Comment: So is it advised to do this for every relation between tables? For example I have a `cookies` table which stores the username instead of the id, should I add this as well as a foreign key? Currently I set the username to `unique`, but what is actually the difference between an `index` and `unique`? I just read that an index doesn't need to be unique, so why would you not-index everything?

Comment: For every _important_ one it _could_ be wise. It has of course a (small) performance hit (checking existing reference on insert/update), and for some volatile data you may just care less whether it's 100% guaranteed correct. About yout cookies table: I would (1) never use a username there if I have an id available (2) seldomly reference a non-primary key and (3) you'll have to decide for yourself whether it's ok-ish to have a non-existing user in that table. `index` is for fast lookups, `unique` is for fast lookups and _enforces_ that there may be only 1 entry with that value. Different things

Comment: Hmm I see... Wel I guess I'll take the performance hit then, I only have to link 3 other tables to the `user_id`. I thought about putting the id in the cookie information as well, but another post somewhere had me convinced a username with a hash is more clear. Otherwise if someone somehow get's the unhashed version of the hash, he can more easily bruteforce it by trying all id's. Not very plausible, but well. I found out that `ON UPDATE CASCADE` updates the table, so I used that for the name of the user. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Well, hashes need to be salted... but they should be salted with random data, not stuff like usernames ;)

Comment: They're not salted with the username, but the cookie looks as follows: `username_hash`. When a user logs in with the cookie, a new hash is made and the cookie updated. Also, I'm using `bcrypt`, so no need to salt manually.